# Should i disconnect my prisma client after every query in NextJs?

Tags: database, next.js, prisma

Some months ago, I tried to do somethings with NextJs and mongoose, but I got a lot of problems about too many connections in my mongo database. I think the main problem was the NextJs way to do the things. Now Im learning about NextJs + Prisma with Postgresql, do i need end my connections when I end queries?

When i tried use mongoose, I create some cache for the database to not create a connection everytime, but the same thing kept happening: Too many connections. Its the same for prisma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With prisma it's possible to instantiate and not create many connections like shown
[here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices)

hope this solves your problem